# Knitr produces only half of plot

Tags: r, plot, knitr, lattice

I am having trouble with the final making of `.md` and `.html` files:

the plot, which should contain 2 facets appears in `.md` only with one.

the same R script produces correct plot. I tried `lattice` and `ggplot2` systems -result is the same: plot is correct in Rstudio (Mac) and loses 1 facet in `.md` and `.html`.

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(steps ~ interval | day_type, data = mean_tsd_final, layout = c(1, 2),
       type="l", xlab = "Interval", ylab = "Number of steps")

> str(mean_tsd_final)
'data.frame':   576 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ interval: int  0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 ...
 $ day_type: Factor w/ 2 levels "weekday","weekend": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ steps   : num  2.251 0.445 0.173 0.198 0.099 ...
```

Produced by R-script

[image: Produced by R-script]

Produced by the same code by knitr

[image: Produced by the same code by knitr]

Comment: Added to the question, thx!

Comment: Yes, I meant `mean_tsd_final` but you got it. I also meant a `dput` instead of `str` since that helps us input your data. But from the `str`, I would guess that you have a subset when plotting in knitr--you see that `day_type` is a factor with two levels, but I can reproduce this plot when you have a factor with two levels but only one level is present in the data

Comment: Both levels of factor is presented...

Comment: FInally, I found the solution.

The problem was with local language preferences. In R-script I override system defaults and set it to English, UTF8, and I didn't include this part of code to the .rmd file. Thats why function that divide result of weekday function to weekdays and weekends was not working properly and produce only 1 factor level. Now its ok. Thank you, rawr, after your reply I checked whether there is 2 levels of factor variables not only in r-script, but also in  markdown file :)

Comment: You should demonstrate and add an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer is:
Code to set local preferences :

```
## To set it in english
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","en_US.UTF-8")
```

Its important, because we use string comparison to produce factor variables.
Here is code for `making mean_td_final` data frame:

```
##Adding column with type of the day
Activity_data_filled$day_type <- weekdays(as.Date(Activity_data_filled$date))
Activity_data_filled$day_type <- ifelse(Activity_data_filled$day_type %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"),"weekend", "weekday")
Activity_data_filled$day_type <-as.factor(Activity_data_filled$day_type)

##Aggegating by type of the day and time intervals
mean_tsd_final <- aggregate(Activity_data_filled$steps,
                       by=list(Activity_data_filled$interval,
                               Activity_data_filled$day_type),mean)
```

Without local settings overriden, `ifelse` function produce only 1 level "weekday", cause it compares strings "Saturday" and "Sunday" with local names of the days, produced by `weekdays` function. ( russian, in my case).